# Ratio of means for a medical meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, medicine

I am in the process of pooling and analysing data from various studies for a meta-analysis I am working on.

My supervisor (non-statistician) is keen for us to have the ratio of means which was [described here](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-8-32) to compare *intervention 1* (I1) to *intervention 2* (I2) with a view of constructing forest plots with that data using the 95% CI values.

Currently, the results tables (in excel) are structured like this for each measured outcome:

| Study ID | I1 n | I1 baseline mean | I1 baseline SD | I2 n | I2 baseline mean | I2 baseline SD | Post-I1 mean | Post-I1 SD | Post-I2 mean | Post-I2 SD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Study 1 | 100 | xx | xx | 80 | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| Study 2 | 50 | xx | xx | 75 | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| Study 3 | 84 | xx | xx | 80 | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx | xx |

I am after some advice as to how best I can go about doing this?

I've had a look through STATA/SPSS/RevMan's documentation to see if it's possible to get the calculations and graphs done to no avail, so I'm turning now to the experts.

Comment: You could use the `metafor` package in `R` and use its function `escalc` to do the calculations for you (option `measure = "ROM"`). In Stata, you could just program the formulae from Friedrich et al. (2008) manually and feed the resulting effect sizes and standard errors to `metan`.